# Assigning multi value parameter (values) to a local parameter in sql query

Tags: reporting-services, sqlparameter

I have a situation where I need to store the multi value parameter to a local parameter in sql query.
In the SSRS report builder I have created two multi value parameters `@Customer` and `@LogisticsGroup`
And in my SQL query , I have to assign those values to local parameters something like this

```
DECLARE @Acct NVARCHAR(100) , @LgstGroup NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Acct = (@Customer) 
,@LgstGroup = (@LogisticsGroup)
```

But with this kind of approach I'm able to select only one value , if I select two values then the query is failing.

I tried this , but it seems like incorrect syntax.

```
DECLARE @Acct NVARCHAR(100) , @LgstGroup NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Acct IN (@Customer) 
,@LgstGroup IN (@LogisticsGroup)
```

Please help to resolve this issue. Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store delimited values in a parameter. So for example, `@Customer` might have a string of ID's in it like `1,2,3`. The report can concatenate the multiple values into this format using the `Join` function.

Now, in the SQL, one option is to use the `LIKE` operator to search the string. You could write something like:

```
@Customer like '%,' + Column_Name + ',%'
```

However, this approach is inefficient and you have to be careful of partial value matches.

A better approach is to create a user-defined table-valued function that can split the values and treat them like a table. There are plenty of examples out there, it's a pretty simple function. Then in practice it would look like this:

```
WHERE Column_Name in (select * from Split(@Customer))
```

OR

```
INNER JOIN Split(@Customer) ON...
```

Comment: Thanks @Steven, It helped. I used JOIN function in the report builder and used SplitString function. thanks again.